# Expanding dateentry display from m/d/yy to mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: python, date, tkinter, tkcalendar

Using `dateentry` from the [tkcalendar](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) python module, every time I select a date on the widget it shortens it to the `m/d/yy` format. I'd like it to expand to `mm/dd/yyyy` if possible, or at least for the year.

When using the [set_date](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html#tkcalendar.DateEntry.set_date) method, it will display whatever is inputted (string), but then reverts back to the shortened format once another date is clicked.

Is there any way to have it always display the full date? I can't seem to find a format parameter that would allow me to use `%Y` so that's why I ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change how it appears upon selection, you can make a class that inherit `DateEntry` and override the `_select` method.

```
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class CustomDateEntry(DateEntry):

    def _select(self, event=None):
        date = self._calendar.selection_get()
        if date is not None:
            self._set_text(date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
            self.event_generate('<<DateEntrySelected>>')
        self._top_cal.withdraw()
        if 'readonly' not in self.state():
            self.focus_set()

entry = CustomDateEntry(root)
entry._set_text(entry._date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7):

This is possible without overriding `_select` since version 1.5.0, using the `date_pattern` argument (See [documentation](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html)):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

window = tk.Tk()

DateEntry(window, locale='en_US', date_pattern='mm/dd/y').pack()  # custom formatting
DateEntry(window, locale='en_US').pack()  # default formatting
window.mainloop()
```

gives

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank you so much. This answer is shorter and clearer.

Comment: FYI the `date_pattern` option wasn't available yet when Henry Yik's answer was posted.

Comment: Hi Juliette. Indeed I can run my own app. at the design time, but cannot generate an .exe file through use of `pyinstaller.exe` if I include `DateEntry` within the code. Do you have an advice ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Have you tried the solution in the [How Tos](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howtos.html#pyinstaller)?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan You have to use either `import babel.numbers` in main code or `--hidden-import=babel.numbers` with pyinstaller